# How to shift elements of an array to the left without using loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a fixed sized array in Matlab. When I want to insert a new element I do the following:

1. To make room first array element will be overwritten
2. Every other element will be shifted at new location `index-1` ---left shift.
3. The new element will be inserted at the place of last element which becomes empty by shifting the elements.

I would like to do it without using any loops.

Comment: Are you shifting the *entire* array to the left, or just part of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you mean this:

```
A = [ A(1:pos) newElem A((pos+1):end) ]
```

That will insert the variable (or array) `newElem` after position `pos` in array `A`.

Let me know if that works for you!

**[Edit]** Ok, looks like you actually just want to use the array as a shift register. You can do it like this:

```
A = [ A(2:end) newElem ]
```

This will take all elements from the 2nd to the last of `A` and added your `newElem` variable (or array) to the end.

Comment: To get rid of the first element you need `[ A(2:pos) ...`.

Comment: @gnovice I know, the question was quite unclear as one long run-on sentence, `David Heffernan` fixed it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

The [circshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/circshift.html) function is another solution:

> `B = circshift(A,shiftsize)` circularly shifts the values in the array, `A`, by `shiftsize` elements. `shiftsize` is a vector of integer scalars where the `n`-th element specifies the shift amount for the `n`-th dimension of array `A`. If an element in `shiftsize` is positive, the values of `A` are shifted down (or to the right). If it is negative, the values of `A` are shifted up (or to the left). If it is 0, the values in that dimension are not shifted.

Example:

> Circularly shift first dimension values down by 1 and second dimension values to the left by 1.
>
> ```
> A = [ 1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9]
>
> A =
>     1     2     3
>     4     5     6
>     7     8     9
>
> B = circshift(A,[1 -1]);
> B  = 
>     8     9     7
>     2     3     1
>     5     6     4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

simply, remove the first value in the array and append the new one at the end.

```
A(1) = []
A = [A newValue]
```

Numeric example

```
A = [1 2 3 4];
A(1) = [];
A = [A 5];
```

The result is A having values [2, 3, 4, 5]